# Stacking div elements

Tags: html, css

I want to stack some div elements like the picture below without having to manually enter the position of every new div I add. Is there some way I can write a style tha will stack my elements like this? I would like to avoid javascript.

Doing something like:

```
div{
  left:-30px;
}
```

will not work because its gonna move all of them by the same amount.

What I know I can probably do is have smaller divs as big as the gap next to each other and have them contain the bigger ones. The problem with this tho is I want to be able to change the stack order by manipulating the big element's z-index which wont work if they are children of different divs.

[image]
Here is a stack snippet:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
#div_1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#div_2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#div_3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#div_4 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="div_1">div1</div>
  <div id="div_2">div2</div>
  <div id="div_3">div3</div>
  <div id="div_4">div4</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where is your html/css?

Comment: How are you handling the color?  If you're already doing that manually, it might not be much more work to add the offset.  And if you use a pre-processor like LESS or SASS, it gets even easier.

Comment: i added some code. the color is just for this example, so u can see what im aiming for. The divs are actually all the same color. Hmm neevr heard of less and sass.. ill look into it

Comment: you can get the `:nth-child()` and give background `color:#xxxxxx` for each and give `display: table-cell`; for sub div

Comment: One more question: Do they actually need to overlap, or can they just be adjacent?

Comment: they need to overlap because i want to bring them in the foreground using the zindex and also i want the content to be partially covered. I dont know if this can be done another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are asking for ?

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-right: -50px;
  z-index: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
div:hover {
  z-index: 100
}
#div_1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#div_2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#div_3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#div_4 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="div_1">div1</div>
  <div id="div_2">div2</div>
  <div id="div_3">div3</div>
  <div id="div_4">div4</div>
</body>
```

Comment: wow... a negative margin. Why didnt i think of that?... GENIUS.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dispaly:inline:block` `float:left;`

[image]

```css
body {
  background: #d300ff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.strip {
  width: 100px;
  height: 700px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
.strip1 {
  background: #fe0000;
}
.strip2 {
  background: #ffa901;
}
.strip3 {
  background: #41ff01;
}
.strip4 {
  background: #01b7ff;
}
.strip5 {
  background: #011eff;
}
```

```html
<div class="strip strip1"></div>
<div class="strip strip2"></div>
<div class="strip strip3"></div>
<div class="strip strip4"></div>
<div class="strip strip5"></div>
```

Comment: you can also use `display: table-cell;` instead of `dispaly:inline:block` `float:left;`

Comment: I dont understand jow this is different from just having 100x700 divs next to each other

Comment: height and width is for example purpose only!